# Simple Scrapy crawler not following links & scraping

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

Basically the problem is in following the links

I'm going from page 1..2..3..4..5.....90 pages in total

each page has 100 or so links

Each page is in this format

```
http://www.consumercomplaints.in/lastcompanieslist/page/1
http://www.consumercomplaints.in/lastcompanieslist/page/2
http://www.consumercomplaints.in/lastcompanieslist/page/3
http://www.consumercomplaints.in/lastcompanieslist/page/4
```

This is regex matching rule

```
Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='(http:\/\/www\.consumercomplaints\.in\/lastcompanieslist\/page\/\d+)'),follow=True,callback="parse_data")
```

I'm going to each page and then creating a `Request` object to scrape all the the links in each page

Scrapy only crawls 179 links in total each time and then gives a `finished` status

What am i doing wrong?

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
import urlparse

class consumercomplaints_spider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "test_complaints"
    allowed_domains = ["www.consumercomplaints.in"]
    protocol='http://'

    start_urls = [
        "http://www.consumercomplaints.in/lastcompanieslist/"
    ]

    #These are the rules for matching the domain links using a regularexpression, only matched links are crawled
    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='(http:\/\/www\.consumercomplaints\.in\/lastcompanieslist\/page\/\d+)'),follow=True,callback="parse_data")
    ]


    def parse_data(self, response):
        #Get All the links in the page using xpath selector
        all_page_links = response.xpath('//td[@class="compl-text"]/a/@href').extract()

        #Convert each Relative page link to Absolute page link -> /abc.html -> www.domain.com/abc.html and then send Request object
        for relative_link in all_page_links:
            print "relative link procesed:"+relative_link

            absolute_link = urlparse.urljoin(self.protocol+self.allowed_domains[0],relative_link.strip())
            request = scrapy.Request(absolute_link,
                         callback=self.parse_complaint_page)
            return request


        return {}

    def parse_complaint_page(self,response):
        print "SCRAPED"+response.url
        return {}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get. You need to crawl 90 links? And what is 179 pages?

Comment: @Nabin Edited the question, sorry. I need to follow 90 pages and each page has 100 links to scrape. Scrapy only scrapes 179 in total

Comment: Are you sure all those 100 links inside each page are also in same domain? i.e. __allowed_domain__

Comment: Yes i'm sure. You can check a template of the page by attaching the page_number of the page at the end of the url, like this http://www.consumercomplaints.in/lastcompanieslist/page/2

you can see the big list of links i'm trying to crawl. I get the links using an xpath selector.  This code pasted works. try running the code directly check if needed

Comment: Those links don't have a number at the end of the URL??

Comment: @Nabin each **page** has 100 links. I'm not following the links in each page. I'm following only the **page** and then sending a request object to each link. You can see the **page** links at the footer

Comment: I would love to see you use __yield__ instead of __return__ at first

Comment: @Nabin wow :D that did it. How did you pinpoint that?

Comment: @Nabin Would you write it as an answer please? I can mark it and it might help somebody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use yield instead of return.

> for each new Request object, use `yield request` instead of `return
>   reqeust`

See more about yield [here](https://www.google.com.np/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwjBjq7ExO3GAhUGMaYKHdvsCiU&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F231767%2Fwhat-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python&ei=8-quVYHJBIbimAXb2auoAg&usg=AFQjCNHtyZE-3od0c6GaWNu8WgIR1Schbg&sig2=On68hW8zEh9rme78DPxoHg&bvm=bv.98197061,d.dGY) and the difference between them and reason [here](https://www.google.com.np/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDYQFjAEahUKEwjsr77QxO3GAhVF3KYKHWyiC0Y&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.investopedia.com%2Fask%2Fanswers%2F04%2F090304.asp&ei=DOuuVez5HsW4mwXsxK6wBA&usg=AFQjCNF77EByPR-jFo7LrRzMW_x0oArhog&sig2=RWf9-7ncjany1KJuCjtngA)